# In the rearview mirror

Tags: idioms

for a book I will write a chapter on what the utopian literature said about a certain technology which is commonplace nowadays.
Would something like "XYZ in the rearview mirror" work or would there be a great idiom.

Thanks, Oliver

Comment: All I know is that "20-20 hindsight" will have a whole new meaning come January.

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more context.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe time to revive t[his Q.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334326/a-word-to-describe-political-buyers-remorse)

Comment: One doesn't normally study things in the rear view mirror in detail. The metaphorical mentions of rear view mirrors that I'm used to hearing are more about putting something in the rear view mirror in the sense of choosing to drive away from that thing.

Comment: twenty twenty hindsight from 2020 - nice! thanks!!